# Weak LLN for non independent triangular arrays

Tags: probability

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a bounded, continuous function. Let $X_{i,n}$ (for $i=1\cdots n$, $n \in \mathbb N$)  be a triangular array of iid Random Variables. Let $Y_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $Y_n \to c$ in probability. Can we conclude
$$\lim_n \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n f(Y_n X_{i,n}) \to E[f(c X_{1,1})]$$
in probability?

Edit: All random variables ($X_{i,n}$ and $Y_n$) are jointly independent.